# Neovim lua config: how to append to listchars?

Tags: neovim, vimscript-lua

In a neovim `init.lua` config, I know that I can append to a string like so:

```lua
vim.opt.wildignore:append("*/node_modules/*,*/vendor/*,*/venv/*,*/.venv/*,*/target/*")
```

However, I'm getting errors with the following attempts to append `extends:#` to the default value of `listchars`:

```lua
vim.opt.listchars:append("extends:#")
vim.opt.listchars:append(",extends:#")
vim.opt.listchars:append({"extends:#"})
vim.opt.listchars:append({",extends:#"})
vim.opt.listchars = vim.opt.listchars + "extends:#"
vim.opt.listchars = vim.opt.listchars + ",extends:#"
```

I thought it was perhaps because it's a mapping, but this also failed:

```lua
vim.opt.listchars:append({extends = "#"})
```

EDIT: ^^ this now works on 0.5.1. See below.

I don't see an `:extend()` method, but tried it anyway and it also fails.

It accepts this as valid: `vim.opt.listchars = "extends:#"`

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: There’s an example in help lua-vim-setlocal (search for listchars), at least in the version I checked online. I think you need to use a table.

Comment: The example shows how to set listchars: `vim.opt.listchars = { space = '_', tab = '>~' }` but not how to *append* to the default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of nvim 0.5.1, on MacOS and Linux, it appears that the `vim.opt.listchars:append` in my original question now works, and for some reason setting the map values as in `vim.opt.listchars.extends = "e"` or `vim.opt.listchars.tab = "t"` no longer works.

```
vim.opt.listchars:append({ extends = "#" })
print(vim.inspect(vim.opt.listchars:get()))
```

Answer (score 2):

The `'listchars'` option is implemented as a Lua table (akin to a Dict in Vim, possibly more similar to an object in JavaScript), so what you need to only change the `extends` setting is:

```
vim.opt.listchars.extends = "#"
```

Or, also valid:

```
vim.opt.listchars["extends"] = "#"
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is no longer working, neovim 0.5.1 MacOS or Arch Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Actual this works (from the official doc: https://neovim.io/doc/user/lua.html):
`vim.opt.listchars = { space = '_', tab = '>~' }`

In my case I got to add (init.lua or outsourced file for global-lua-settings)

```
vim.opt.listchars = {eol = '↵'}   
vim.opt.list = true
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, but the question was specifically about extending the existing value, not overwriting it; I also mentioned your example in my comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/31811/neovim-lua-config-how-to-append-to-listchars/36574#comment58568_31811

Answer (score 0):

You can use:
`vim.opt.listchars:append({ eol = '↵' })`
or `vim.opt.listchars + { eol = '↵' }`
to append
and `vim.opt.listchars:prepend({ eol = '↵' })`
or `vim.opt.listchars ^ { eol = '↵' }`
to prepend to nvim Option objects.

Source:
https://neovim.io/doc/user/lua.html#vim.env

Comment: I had to add `vim.opt.list = true` to make the config work